# ics/ical recurring event without dtstart?

Tags: icalendar

Farmers Market week is the 1st Sunday in August. The following 
ics/ical code almost works:

`BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Farmers Market Week
UID:6b4f9fae9bdb8f09591408205e7de96ef4da1b15
DTSTART:20150101T000000
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=8;BYDAY=1SU
DURATION:P1W
END:VEVENT`

but generates an "extra" event on 1 Jan 2015.

This makes sense (since DTSTART is 1 Jan 2015), but is there any way I 
can avoid this without having to calculate the first Sunday in August 
directly?

In other words, can I have recurring events with no DTSTART (or an automatically created DTSTART)?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can add an EXDATE to exclude the date corresponding to the DTSTART though. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.1

That said, it is still better to have a DTSTART that corresponds to the RRULE. Some clients may not like the above construct.